# Negative vSpace in header with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to put my chapter title in the vertical center of the figures height. 
My code is the following:

```
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{Figures/logo_without_name.png} \vspace*{-0.25cm}\rightmark}
```

This leads to following result:
[image: Sitation at the moment]

Where I want the chaptername is shown in the following:
[image: Wanted result]

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

The MWE as requested (thanks for the hint!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \rhead{\includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{example.png} \vspace* \rightmark}
\begin{document} 
Lorem Ipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can try to use `\raisebox` to change the position, height and depth of the image.

Comment: You can also `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` in the preamble, and then `\includegraphics[...,valign=c]{..}`.

Comment: @LockeLamora: Please write up a separate answer to this problem rather than including it in the original post. Then you can also [accept it](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764) later.

Comment: The example in the question is not working. So it is not a MWE as mentioned by Bobyandbob. Please, have a look at the link in his comment.

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION**:

As Schweinebacke suggested me, I used `\raisebox` and it works perfectly with it:

```
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{Figures/logo_without_name.png} \raisebox{0.5cm}[0cm][0cm]{\rightmark}}
```